# How to only select unique user_id from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql:

```
SELECT `activity`.* 
FROM `activity`,`exchange`  
WHERE `activity`.`id` != 0 
AND `activity`.`type` !=6 
AND (`activity`.`type` = 4 OR `activity`.`type` = 5)
AND (`exchange`.`id` = `activity`.`user_id`) 
AND (`exchange`.`photo` != 0) 
ORDER BY `activity`.`id` DESC  
LIMIT 4
```

Currently I get repeated user_id in the results. How can I get non-repeating user_ids from this so they are distinct?

Exchange is the user table.

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `add_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12583 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `activity`
--

INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `user_id`, `type`, `link`, `time`, `add_text`) VALUES
(12567, 11615, 4, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&lang=es&discussionID=1131&t=viewDiscussion', 1360941086, 'for everyone wants to learn spanish'),
(12560, 6091, 4, 'Random-topics&lang=&discussionID=1130&t=viewDiscussion', 1360936869, 'Valentine''s Day'),
(12542, 11603, 5, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=966&page=', 1360923369, 'AMIGA ALEMANA :)'),
(12541, 11603, 5, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1036&page=', 1360923340, 'Want to re-learn Spanish'),
(12540, 11603, 5, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1114&page=', 1360923203, 'Quiero practicar mi espanol!'),
(12539, 11603, 5, 'Cultura-y-Sociedad---EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=106&page=', 1360922991, 'Â¿EstÃ¡s de acuerdo con que se hagan corridas de toro?'),
(12532, 11604, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1112&page=', 1360920608, 'Looking for a French Penpal!'),
(12527, 11495, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=54&page=', 1360909410, 'Why are you learning English?'),
(12503, 11100, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=54&page=', 1360876079, 'Why are you learning English?'),
(12502, 11100, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=54&page=', 1360876051, 'Why are you learning English?'),
(12491, 9641, 5, 'Culture-and-Society---English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1129&page=', 1360874309, 'Rock music groups from your country?'),
(12490, 1874, 4, 'Culture-and-Society---English&discussionID=1129&t=viewDiscussion', 1360870935, 'Rock music groups from your country?'),
(12478, 11609, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1112&page=', 1360856071, 'Looking for a French Penpal!'),
(12448, 11604, 4, 'Aide-demandÃ©e,-en-franÃ§ais&lang=es&discussionID=1128&t=viewDiscussion', 1360832732, 'Apprendre le franÃ§ais'),
(12442, 11604, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1123&page=', 1360832130, 'FranÃ§ais!'),
(12433, 11605, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=54&page=', 1360830795, 'Why are you learning English?'),
(12406, 887, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1127&page=', 1360796193, 'silver'),
(12405, 11600, 4, 'Learning-English&lang=&discussionID=1127&t=viewDiscussion', 1360796100, 'silver'),
(12399, 11596, 4, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&lang=es&discussionID=1126&t=viewDiscussion', 1360794605, 'Je voudrais apprendre le franÃ§aise'),
(12384, 11595, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=173&page=', 1360791086, 'What is your favourite song? '),
(12349, 11578, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=478&page=', 1360771365, 'What kind of music do you like and why?'),
(12306, 11578, 5, 'Culture-and-Society---English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1012&page=', 1360708606, 'Why are you learning a foreign language?'),
(12292, 6091, 5, '&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=330&page=', 1360693956, 'Which day of the week do you hate the most? Why?'),
(12262, 11567, 5, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1114&page=', 1360661625, 'Quiero practicar mi espanol!'),
(12238, 11544, 5, 'Learning-English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=909&page=', 1360648815, 'What instrument(s) do you play?'),
(12195, 887, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1077&page=', 1360624305, 'Resources to Learn French'),
(12135, 6091, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=471&page=', 1360599702, 'Connaissez-vous le Verlan?'),
(12134, 2933, 5, 'Travel,_Live_and_Study_Abroad_-_English&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1124&page=', 1360596914, 'Would you like to make an exchange?'),
(12131, 3934, 5, 'Apprendre-le-FranÃ§ais&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=471&page=', 1360595290, 'Connaissez-vous le Verlan?'),
(12123, 11543, 5, 'Aprender-EspaÃ±ol&t=viewDiscussion&discussionID=1114&page=', 1360587427, 'Quiero practicar mi espanol!');
```

[SQL Fiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/693e5)

Comment: You might be able to use `DISTINCT` but without seeing your data you might have a column that could prevent this.  Can you post some sample data?

Comment: data has been posted above

Comment: If a single user has two activities, how should the output look?

Comment: So do you want some sort of aggregate? since userID isn't a unique field, you're going to get repeated user ID's unless you either do an aggregate or just select the distinct userID.

Comment: +1 posting details as one likes it. ;-)

Comment: if the user has two activities, it should only display the latest activity.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by aggregate! I just don't want repeating activities from a single user - or rather I want to show how many different people are on the site, not just a single user who may have just done 10 things spamming up the page

Comment: add the `exchange` details

Comment: If you just want to show the different people on the site, you can just SELECT Distinct UserID FROM Activity. (I said Activity because you haven't mentioned a users table yet). Can you put an example of what you would like to be returned in your question?

Comment: @Scotch I want to show a list of recent activities just as my original SQL does, but WITHOUT repeated users. The exchange table is the users table

Comment: See my answer and if that is something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close -- gets the max time associated with a user and activity:

```
SELECT `activity`.* 
FROM `exchange`
    JOIN `activity` ON `exchange`.`id` = `activity`.`user_id`
    JOIN (
        Select User_Id, MAX(Time) timeMax
        FROM Activity
        WHERE `activity`.`id` != 0 
            AND `activity`.`type` !=6 
            AND (`activity`.`type` = 4 OR `activity`.`type` = 5)
        GROUP BY User_Id
    ) maxActivity ON `activity`.`user_id` = maxActivity.User_Id 
            AND `activity`.`Time` = maxActivity.timeMax
WHERE (`exchange`.`photo` != 0) 
ORDER BY `activity`.`id` DESC  
LIMIT 4
```

Here's your Fiddle back: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/693e5/10

BTW -- No need for Activity.Type != 6 -- Just use Activity.Type IN (4,5) -- or keep the OR above.

```
SELECT `activity`.* 
FROM `exchange`
    JOIN `activity` ON `exchange`.`id` = `activity`.`user_id`
    JOIN (
        Select User_Id, MAX(Time) timeMax
        FROM Activity
        WHERE `activity`.`id` != 0 
            AND `activity`.`type` IN (4, 5)
        GROUP BY User_Id
    ) maxActivity ON `activity`.`user_id` = maxActivity.User_Id 
            AND `activity`.`Time` = maxActivity.timeMax
WHERE (`exchange`.`photo` != 0) 
ORDER BY `activity`.`id` DESC  
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Distinct or Group BY? OR use Joins in your FROM to join the tables? Maybe if you post some data it will be more clear

```
SELECT DISTINCT `activity`.* 
FROM `activity`,`exchange`  
WHERE `activity`.`id` != 0 
AND `activity`.`type` !=6 
AND (`activity`.`type` = 4 OR `activity`.`type` = 5)
AND (`exchange`.`id` = `activity`.`user_id`) 
AND (`exchange`.`photo` != 0) 
ORDER BY `activity`.`id` DESC  
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user id is a unique integer, you might consider making the user id the primary key for your table.

Comment: I'm not sure what your business requirements are, but you might consider SELECT TOP 1 then the rest of your query, depending on what value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be something that you could use?

```
    Select user_id, max(time), add_text FROM activity GROUP BY user_id
```